# Dojo Dijit TimeTextBox Not Working When Pulled Into Page With AJAX

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have one main page with menu buttons. When clicked, they change the main "content" area with AJAX. In the header of this page I have all of the appropriate Dojo references.
I know the AJAX works because i have successfully pulled in and displayed data in the content area, and I know the Dojo Dijit TimeTextBox works because I have successfully displayed it before I make any calls with AJAX.

When I try to make a call with AJAX and pull in new input fields for the TimeTextBox widget, they display only as regular text boxes, and seem to ignore the fact that I have them set to be the TimeTextBox.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/adminPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/adminStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script  
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" 
            djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.TimeTextBox");
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox"], 
        function(ready, TimeTextBox){
            ready(function(){
                new TimeTextBox({name: "timeInput", value: new Date(),
                    constraints: {
                        timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
                        clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
                        visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
                        visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
                    }
                }, "timeInput");
            });
        });

        function getPage(page) 
        {
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin"+page+".php",   
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {              
            $('#content').html(html);
                            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
                            }
    });

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <span class="headerTitle">Lehman Nursery</span>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <input type='text' name='date1' id='time1' value='T15:00:00'
    data-dojo-type='dijit.form.TimeTextBox' 
    required='true' />
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <a onclick="getPage('Home')">
                <div id="homeButton" class="menuAppearance">
                    <img src="images/icons/home.png"/><br />
                </div>
            </a>
            <a onclick="getPage('Links')">
                <div class="button menuAppearance">
                    <div class="menuTitle"><img src="images/icons/links.png"/><br />Links</div>
                    <div class="description">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a onclick="getPage('Hours')">
                <div class="button menuAppearance">
                    <div class="menuTitle"><img src="images/icons/pictures.png"/><br />Pictures</div>
                    <div class="description">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a onclick=getPage('Events')>
                <div class="button menuAppearance">
                    <div class="menuTitle"><img src="images/icons/events.png"/><br />Events</div>
                    <div class="description">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a onclick=getPage('Feedback')>
                <div class="button menuAppearance">
                    <div class="menuTitle"><img src="images/icons/feedback.png"/><br />Feedback</div>
                    <div class="description">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="date1" id="time1" value="T15:00:00"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox"
    onChange="require(['dojo/dom'], function(dom){dom.byId('val').value=dom.byId('time1').value.toString().replace(/.*1970\s(\S+).*/,'T$1')})"
    required="true" /></form>
```

^^That is the data being pulled in

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Did the code stored in a web site? If yes, could you give me a link?

Answer (score 0):

Are the css files for those `dijit`s pulled up? You might want to `require` them at the beginning (when the page loads) which get cached and will be used when the `dijit`s are pulled via AJAX.

EDIT: Not sure but can suggest you try to add `startup()` call for the widget you created.

Comment: How exactly would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

it apears to me like you are forgoetting to call:

```
dojo.parser.parse();
```

after setting the content i your ajax call. it should look like this:

```
function getPage(page) 
{
$.ajax({
    url: "admin"+page+".php",   
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {              
        $('#content').html(html);
        dojo.parser.parse();
        $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
}
```

the dojo parser will not execute by itself, it is too resourses expensive to do that, so each time the content changes so you add a dijit you moust call dojo.parser.parse();

Comment: I added it in and it didn't work, but I believe you are on the right track.  Is it possible to use the parser _after_ I load the content with AJAX?  Rather than just when the page initially loads?

Comment: yes that is what I was refeing to, you are supposed to use it after the content is loaded with AJAX, well maybe i don't now how jquery handles "$('#content').html(html);" but you should parse() after the html content has been set